# How to fix 'Eliminate render blocking resource' in Lighthouse Audit

Tags: javascript, css, performance, lighthouse

I was trying to fix the 'Eliminate render blocking issue' from Lighthouse audit for my web application.I have read from many articles about defer and async as the solution for this warning. I had tried it both but still nothing helps me to increase my app's performance. I am still finding the same warning.

Following are the different way I have tried so for:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/v2/_assets/css/theme.css" media="all" async>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/v2/_assets/css/theme.css" media="all" defer>
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com/v2/_assets/css/theme.css" media="all" as="style">
<script src="https://example.com/v2/sample.js" defer>
```

Is there anything i have missed out? Can anyone help me to get out solution for this?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Does [this](https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/) help?

Comment: Have you tried moving the script to the bottom of the body?